# Python - Tkinter My Entry isn't displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey i have troubles with my code, my entry isn't displayed, there is an error in my code but i don't see where. If someone can display the big frame on top and the entry on the bottom just tell me how :)

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root['bg']='white'
root.title('Next Note')

root.minsize(800, 500)
root.maxsize(800,500)


frame = Frame(root, bg='light blue', height=300, width = 780 )
frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=30)
frame.grid_propagate(0)

text = StringVar()
text_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text, bg='white', border=1, width = 100)
text_entry.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=50, pady=750,)
text_entry.grid_propagate(0)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `pady=750` pushes it below the screen so you can't see it.

Comment: nop even with 200 i can't see it

Comment: Then try 0. It woks for me

Comment: nop still nothing

Comment: That Frame is very wide, so column 1 is very wide, which pushes column 2 (where the Entry is) off the right side of the window. So either reduce the width of the Frame, or put the Entry in column 1.

Comment: but my entry is centred and i want it a little bit lower how can i do that ?

Comment: Try `pady=60`, or similar. IIRC, the number for `pady` is _not_ measured in pixels, it's in lines (that is, lines of text), because it's a text widget, and the height of a line depends on the font you're using.

Comment: I can't i am sorry i don't have any reputation :/

Comment: done thank's but why padx and pady are useless ?

Comment: They aren't exactly useless, they just don't behave the way you expect. ;) That's the "fun" thing about GUI programing, you need to experiment a bit to make it do what you want. It also helps to be pretty familiar with the docs, but it's easy to misinterpret stuff in the docs, so when you read stuff, do a little experiment to make sure it does what you think it does.

Comment: It can be a bit bewildering at first, but if you put in the effort eventually it all comes together. I've only been using Tkinter for a few years, but I've had a fair bit of experience with several other GUI frameworks, so it wasn't too hard for me to pick up Tkinter. However, there are some people here who've been using it for ages, and some (like Bryan Oakley) who used Tcl/Tk (the engine underneath Tkinter) for years before that, probably long before you were born. So when you get stuck, if you come here and write a good question, you'll probably get good help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put the Entry into column 1, reduced its `pady`, so now it's visible. I made it green so its easier to see. I also got rid of the evil `from tkinter import *` wildcard import.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root['bg']='white'
root.title('Next Note')

root.minsize(800, 500)
root.maxsize(800,500)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='light blue', height=300, width=780 )
frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=30)
frame.grid_propagate(0)

text = tk.StringVar()
text_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=text, bg='green', border=1, width = 50)
text_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=50, pady=50)
text_entry.grid_propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```